# Can't find model for source store

Tags: objective-c, model

I am new to objective C development.  In inherited someone else's project.

I see that in his project, he has a folder called Model.  In it are the files

```
Product.h
Product.m
Compatible.h
Compatible.m
Model.h
Model.m
MyProject.xcdatamodeld
```

A few days ago I created two new files called Warehouse.h and Warehouse.m, following the style of coding I saw in Product.h and Product.m.  I also wrote some functions in Model.h and Model.m that helped me grab new Warehouses.  I then created a new Entity in MyProject.xcdatamodeld by opening that file up in XCode, clicking Add Entity, renaming the entity and adding the necessary attributes.

I was able to use this new class/model in the rest of my project.

Today, i decided to add some new properties to my Warehouse.m.  I then added new attributes to the MyProject.xcdatamodeld by clicking on the new attribute buttons.

Now my project crashes right when it starts up, giving me the error `Can't find model for source store`.

Am I doing something wrong?  I vaguely remember someone telling me it's a headache of the model changes.  Can someone recommend me reading on the subject matter? And how i can fix my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to MyProject.xcdatamodeld.  Then clicked on "Configuration" in the left navigation.  Then I noticed a table showed up with the following contents:

```
Entity      Abstract        Class
Compatible  un-checkbox     Compatible
Product     un-checkbox     Product
Warehouse   un-checkbox
```

I noticed that the Warehouse row didn't have a value for Class.  So i typed in Warehouse in to it.  Then everything worked.